# javascript map(val , index) , which condition val is variable and string

Tags: javascript, lambda

After few research and test I'm still confuse about the map expression `map((k,i) => { ... } )`

Why my `k` is a string instead of variable when i create an object `{ k : arr[i] }`

> exemple 1

```js
let name = 'test.val2'    
let test = ['name','ext'].map((k,i) => console.log({k :name.split('.')[i]}))
```

> exemple 2

```js
let name = 'test.val2'
let test = ['name','ext'].map((k,i) => console.log(k ,name.split('.')[i]))
```

> exemple 3

```js
let name = 'test.val2'
let test = ['name','ext'].map((k,i) => {
  let obj = {}
  obj[k] = name.split('.')[i]
  console.log(obj)
})
```

Comment: If you want to create an object with property name = value of `k`, try `{[k]: "value"}`

Comment: @James yea thanks , this exactly what im looking for .